# Laravel for tenancy does not redirect to tenant domain after registration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, multi-tenant

I have created a fresh laravel application, and then have installed tenancyforlaravel: https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/quickstart. I have followed the docs and everything works okay so far. But lastly i have seen a problem, if i try to register from my central domain ex: localhost.com by this form,

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        ....

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="tenant" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Tenant Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="tenant" type="tenant" class="form-control @error('tenant') is-invalid @enderror" name="tenant" value="{{ old('tenant') }}" required autocomplete="tenant">

                                @error('tenant')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        ...

                        <div class="row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I use tenant name also per domain. And if i do a registration from this form show me an error and does not redirect me to the new tenant witch is just register. If i register for example tenant name `foo` then i need to go manually `foo.localhost.com` but how can i do user to redirect automatically to their domain or tenant name as is on my form

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        // return User::create([
        //     'name' => $data['name'],
        //     'email' => $data['email'],
        //     'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        // ]);
        
        // Get the tenant domain
        $site_url = \config('app.url');
        $tenantDomain = $data['tenant'];
        $parsed_url = parse_url($site_url);
        $scheme = $parsed_url['scheme'] ?? '';
        $host = $parsed_url['host'] ?? '';
        $new_url = $scheme . '://' . $tenantDomain. '.' . $host;
        
        // If the original URL had a path, append it to the new URL
        if (isset($parsed_url['path'])) {
            $new_url .= $parsed_url['path'];
        }

        // If the original URL had a query string, append it to the new URL
        if (isset($parsed_url['query'])) {
            $new_url .= '?' . $parsed_url['query'];
        }

        // If the original URL had a fragment, append it to the new URL
        if (isset($parsed_url['fragment'])) {
            $new_url .= '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'];
        }
        
        // Create Tenant
        $tenant = Tenant::create([
            'id'  =>  $data['tenant'],
        ]);

        // Assign domain to domains table
        $tenant->domains()->create([
            'domain'    => $tenantDomain . '.' . $host,
        ]);

        // Create User for current Tenant
        $user = $tenant->run(function () use ($data, $tenant) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name'      => $data['name'],
                'email'     => $data['email'],
                'password'  => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);

            // Run the permission seeder
            Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'PermissionTableSeeder']);

            // Create Admin role for tenant
            $role = Role::create(['name' => 'Admin']);
            $permissions = Permission::pluck('id', 'id')->all();
            $role->syncPermissions($permissions);

            $user->assignRole([$role->id]);

            return $user;
        });
        
        // return $user;
    }
```

`Note:` On the central db i register only `domains` and `tenants` no user, user will register on the `tenantname` db and then on the table users